# Irish slang word for working and taking state welfare payment

Tags: slang, hiberno-english

I think I heard this somewhere before. Is there an Irish (British maybe?) word for taking money from the state for unemployment, but then actually working a job secretly on the side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing a **Nixer**.  Particularly in Dublin slang.

Google will find you many refs, including these.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nixer

http://www.revenue.ie/en/business/shadow-economy/nixers.html

Comment: This isn't correct. Nixers are small, casual jobs taken in addition to regular employment. E.g. a plumber who works for a company but takes small jobs directly from customers on evenings or weekends. While it's implied that income tax/VAT etc. aren't paid, it's not the right word for someone on the dole. The links you've provided say the same thing.